# How to create layout for typical phone screen 480x800 hdpi?

Tags: android, android-layout

`RecyclerView` item layout, padding and margins are conflicts on typical phone screen **480x800 hdpi**. Other than 480*800 hdpi, layout design showing perfect for normal screens.

Samsung J1 Ace DisplayMetrics values :

```
DisplayMetrics{density=1.5, width=480, height=800, scaledDensity=1.1850001, xdpi=217.714, ydpi=216.17}
```

I have created layout folder for `layout-w320dp` and replaced below `xml`, which was working fine on normal layouts (Normal mobile screens).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardViewDashboard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/paddingDefault"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/paddingDefault"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
        card_view:cardMaxElevation="@dimen/paddingDefault"
        card_view:contentPadding="@dimen/paddingDefault">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="15dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/circle_layout"
                android:layout_width="85dp"
                android:layout_height="85dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_legend"
                android:gravity="center">

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgViewDashboard"
                    android:layout_width="36dp"
                    android:layout_height="36dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center|center_horizontal"
                    android:tint="@color/toolBar"
                    card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_dashboard" />

            </LinearLayout>


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtViewDashboard"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imgViewDashboard"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/title_dashboard"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance"
                android:textColor="@color/toolBar" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Layout which having padding and margin problems for **480*800 hdpi** screenshots FYR, also i have tried SO answers but i didn't get any ideas.

[image]

Anybody knows, how to resolve this issue? Please share your ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a new `layout` folder inside res for support.

Regarding dimensions, please check below link. That will help you.
https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

You can create a new `layout-large` folder in `res`. Add your XML in this folder. That way you can manage it.
e.g.

```
res/layout-large/activity_main.xml
```

You can create new layout as per your requirement from Android studio. 
Right click on layout=>New=> layout resource file

[image]

Customize as per your requirement and generate.

Comment: Yes, i have tried this link too. By creating `layout-large`, its reflecting only in tablets not in `480*800 hdpi` mobile. By creating `layout-small`, its reflecting only on small devices.

Comment: You can create a custom layout as per your requirement using Android studio.

Comment: My `xml` is working fine on all layouts except on 480*800. Actually layout has to supports for 480*800 hdpi, so what type custom layout i have to create. Above question contains `DisplayMetrics` values. Already i have tried `layout-normal`, `layout-sw240dp`, `layout-w240dp` but nothing fits for 4800*800 hdpi (i.e) samsung J1 Ace mobile